# Android Listview onclick random selection

Tags: android, listview

I have FAQ as List view,It will contain a question, an answer and an image view.I am attaching the screenshot below.when click on the first item it will make the answer of the first row will be visible (initially visibility gone) .The problem is it will also made the tenth item visible.The same situation is occurred till the fourth item

```
       @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.faq_listitem, parent,false);

        holder.mQuestionnoTextView= convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_no);
        holder.mQuestionTextView =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);
        holder.mAnswerTextView =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.answer);
        holder.viewMore=convertView.findViewById(R.id.show_more) ;

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    int number=position+1;

    holder.mQuestionnoTextView.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0})", number));
    holder.mQuestionTextView.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}", getItem(position).getQuestion()));
    holder.mAnswerTextView.setText(getItem(position).getAnswer());
    final TextView answers=holder.mAnswerTextView;
    final ImageView arrow=holder.viewMore;

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                if (answers.isShown()) {
                    answers.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    arrow.setRotation(0);
                } else {
                    answers.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    arrow.setRotation(180);
                }
                //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: use view holder and you manually need to save the visible positions and show/hide them

Comment: can you give an example code please

Comment: can you add complete adapter code

Comment: please check I had added

Comment: Done check it , if you have any more problems please do comment

Comment: you didnt gave the code yet

Comment: I posted answer check below

Comment: do you know realm db?

Comment: Nope I use room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what you need to do .

make a global variable  `List<Integer> savedPositions = new ArrayList<>();`

```
if(savedPositions.contains(position)){
        answers.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        arrow.setRotation(180);
 }else{
      answers.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      arrow.setRotation(0);
  }

 convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                if (savedPositions.contains(position)) {
                    savedPositions.remove((Integer) position);
                    answers.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    arrow.setRotation(0);

                } else {
                    savedPositions.add(position);
                    answers.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    arrow.setRotation(180);
                }
               notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use**

```
answers.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE
```

**Instead of**

```
 answers.isShown()
```

Try this

```
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (answers.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
                answers.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                arrow.setRotation(0);
            } else {
                answers.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                arrow.setRotation(180);
            }
            //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });
```

If you want to maintain visibly inside recyclerview or in listview have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51744548/7666442

Comment: Another one great answer +1

Comment: I don't think this will work because the views will be recycled and visibility cant be trusted .

Comment: @Redman yes that's why i have add link https://stackoverflow.com/a/51744548/7666442

Answer (score 0):

```
if (arrow.getRotation()==0) {
         answers.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 } else {
         answers.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
```

add this condition outside of onClickListener in your adapter if you didn't add.