# Button Like is blinking in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

[image]

I have problem with recyclerview. Each time i click button Love i want to change color and text to red but when i swipe up and down my button is blinking to another position. Here is my code:

```
holder.layoutLove.setOnClickListener {
        selectedPosition = holder.adapterPosition
        notifyDataSetChanged()

        Toast.makeText(context, position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
    if (selectedPosition == holder.adapterPosition) {
            holder.tvLove.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            holder.imvLove.setImageResource(R.drawable.liked)

    }
```

Comment: Have a look this answer your will get idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744486/how-to-maintain-visibllity-of-recyclerview-item-in-adapter-class/51744548#51744548

Comment: use notifyItemInsert for that particular position

Answer (score 0):

You just escaping `else` conditions in your `clickListeners`

```
holder.layoutLove.setOnClickListener {  

    if (position == holder.adapterPosition) {
         holder.tvLove.setTextColor(Color.RED)
         holder.imvLove.setImageResource(R.drawable.liked)
    }else{  
         holder.tvLove.setTextColor(Color.GREY)
         holder.imvLove.setImageResource(R.drawable.unlike)
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged()

    Toast.makeText(context, position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

May this code helps you.

If it still does not help you Use the Model Class to handle this.

Comment: Thanks you but button is still blinking i will try model class to handle this

Comment: Can you please update your question with `xml` & `RecyclerView's Adapter` class

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this code, I don't see any blinks:

private class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
    private List<Boolean> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public void updateData(List<Boolean> data) {
        this.data.clear();
        this.data.addAll(data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.view.setBackgroundColor(data.get(position) ? getColor(R.color.colorAccent) : getColor(R.color.black));
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                data.set(position, !data.get(position));
                CustomAdapter.this.notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final ImageView view;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue should be either in the model or on the view side. I propose use model as a single source for the view state.