# I am using GridView when I scroll it the state of favourite button is changed to default state

Tags: java, android

**I am using gridview to show the images and text just like an simple e-commerce app do having a favorite icon ,When I scroll the view the item that I have marked as favorite is changed to its default state i.e. (UN-marked),,Although, just like a RecyclerView but I am not using it so cannot find any clue why the view is changing ,answers with a proper explanation are appreciated.**

Adapter Class

```
public class Category_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    String name[], img[];
    int price[];
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public Category_Adapter(Context context, String[] name, String[] img, int price[]) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.price = price;
        this.name = name;
        this.img = img;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    Category_Adapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return name.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class Holderr {
        TextView product_name;
        Button addCart;
        TextView price_pro;
        ImageView product_img, mark, marked;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Holderr holderr = new Holderr();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_category_grid, null);
        holderr.product_img = (ImageView
                ) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageofitem);
        holderr.addCart = rowView.findViewById(R.id.cartmein);
        holderr.mark = rowView.findViewById(R.id.markFav);
        holderr.marked = rowView.findViewById(R.id.markedFav);
        holderr.product_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.productkanam);
        holderr.price_pro = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.priceof_item);
        holderr.price_pro.setText("Rs. " + price[position]);
        holderr.product_name.setText(name[position]);
        Glide.with(mContext).load(img[position]).into(holderr.product_img);
        holderr.addCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toasty.success(mContext, name[position] + " Added in cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        holderr.mark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holderr.mark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holderr.marked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        holderr.marked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holderr.marked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holderr.mark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Class where I am  setting adapter in GridView

```
public class ViewMoreCategory extends AppCompatActivity {
    GridView gridView;
    ImageButton back, filter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_more_category);
        filter = findViewById(R.id.filter_items);
        gridView = findViewById(R.id.product_cat_grid);
        String name[] = {"Shampoo", "Oil", "Ghee", "Cream", "Shampoo", "Oil", "Ghee", "Cream", "Shampoo", "Oil"};
        String img[] = {"http://pngimg.com/uploads/shampoo/shampoo_PNG18.png", "http://pngimg.com/uploads/shampoo/shampoo_PNG18.png", "http://pngimg.com/uploads/shampoo/shampoo_PNG18.png", "http://pngimg.com/uploads/shampoo/shampoo_PNG18.png", "http://pngimg.com/uploads/shampoo/shampoo_PNG18.png", "http://pngimg.com/uploads/shampoo/shampoo_PNG18.png", "http://pngimg.com/uploads/shampoo/shampoo_PNG18.png", "http://pngimg.com/uploads/shampoo/shampoo_PNG18.png", "http://pngimg.com/uploads/shampoo/shampoo_PNG18.png", "http://pngimg.com/uploads/shampoo/shampoo_PNG18.png"};
        int price[] = {500, 200, 500, 100, 50, 330, 200, 300, 900, 400};
        gridView.setAdapter(new Category_Adapter(ViewMoreCategory.this, name, img, price));
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_toolbar);
        View view = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();
        back = view.findViewById(R.id.backtoHome);
        gridView.setAdapter(new Category_Adapter(this, name, img, price));
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ViewMoreCategory.this, Dashboard.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744486/how-to-maintain-visibllity-of-recyclerview-item-in-adapter-class/51744548#51744548

Comment: Its not a recyclerview read my question properly

Comment: the above link is just hint you need to maintain the state of your fav button

Comment: Its not a recyclerview, but they work similarly. To not use more memory than what is needed views are recycled. So what you need to do in your getView method is to set the state of the button every time, or it will reset.

Comment: @NileshRathod it taking RecyclerView as parameter when I am passing GridView it cannot resolve the View

Comment: @AkshayRohilla take a array of boolean value and make change in array whenever user click on your fav button and also make your fav button condition based on that boolean array

Comment: @NileshRathod kindly add the answer in code so I can get it properly

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to keep the position of selected item

1. Add a property to your `Model class` like below:
   `private int state;`
2. Get the position of selected item then change the value of `state` property
3. Finally change the image of your `imageView` in `getView` in your `Adapter` ad you need

Hope it will help you